# How to use RBAC with keycloak and nuxt

Tags: vue.js, jwt, nuxt.js, keycloak, openid-connect

I am currently trying to use Keycloak for authentication and authorization with a nuxt application. I am able to direct all authentication to Keycloak and get a OIDC JWT Token in response. The nuxt application is able to parse the response and grant access.

But it seems that not all of the information from the OIDC JWT token is available to my nuxt application. I would like to know which roles the user has, alongside with other attributes from the token.

Looking at the `this.$auth.user` I only get this information:

```
{ 
  "sub": "af52eefc-377e-4fd4-8da7-e1c15118acb8", 
  "email_verified": true, 
  "name": "Kenneth Larsen", 
  "preferred_username": "xyz", 
  "given_name": "Kenneth", 
  "family_name": "Larsen", 
  "email": "xyz@mail.com" 
}
```

I am able to get the full token from `this.$auth.strategy.token.get()` and if I decode it at jwt.io I get something like this:

```
{
  "exp": 1615519947,  
  "iat": 1615519647,
  "auth_time": 1615519285,
  "jti": "054ef275-fe50-40b8-b283-087f544b3afc",
  "iss": "https://example.com/auth/realms/testrealm",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "af52eefc-377e-4fd4-8da7-e1c15118acb8",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "example.com",
  "session_state": "98f74bbd-a626-4757-96de-4d860bdd45d1",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "https://example.com",
  ],
  "realm_access": {
     "roles": [
        "offline_access",
        "myrole01",
        "myrole02",
        "uma_authorization"
      ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid email profile",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "Kenneth Larsen",
  "preferred_username": "xyz",
  "given_name": "Kenneth",
  "family_name": "Larsen",
  "email": "xyz@email.com"
```

}

I am aware that I could parse the token, but I expect that this is already done. Just can't find it anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Got a bit closer to a solution. When adding a mapper in KeyCloak using builtin mapper realm_roles and adding this to userinfo the roles are now available in $auth. Then you have to setup scopeKey in the auth configuration to "realm_access.roles" and finally you are able to use the roles from Keycloak

Answer (score 0):

define scopes in the configuration like below

```js
 keycloak: {
        scheme: 'oauth2',
        endpoints: {
          authorization: `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/auth`,
          token: `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token`,
          logout: `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=` + encodeURIComponent(String(process.env.REMOTE_API))
        },
        token: {
          property: 'access_token',
          type: 'Bearer',
          name: 'Authorization',
          maxAge: 1800 // Can be dynamic ?
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'refresh_token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 // Can be dynamic ? 
        },
        responseType: 'code',
        grantType: 'authorization_code',
        clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: ["openid","address","roles","microprofile-jwt","email","phone","profile"],
        codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
      }
    }
```

Then you will get role list from the nuxt auth. here is a sample code

```js
// get role list
const roles = this.$auth.user.groups;
// check role exists or not. Here 'user' is a custom role
const hasUserRole = roles.includes('user');
```